# Android Show Text Where I Click

Tags: java, android, click, position, display

I have a question.
I am in Android Studio and have a button that should show an image and text when clicked but the text and the image should be displayed exactly at the position where I clicked.
Is that possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use **onTouchListener** for get x, y positions then you give margin the imageview/textview for set position.

Sample:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            // imageview/textview set margin from x/y
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, how can I set the margin from the image? I made it with setX() / setY(). but the position where I click on the button is not the same with the position from the whole screen.

Comment: I have set the button in the middle of the screen with all margins to 0.

Comment: Just set margin like margin top from y and margin left from x.

Comment: but he doesn't suggest setmargin to me.